# Enable Multi-Dex Fails the Azure Devops Xamarin Android Build

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]
When I enable **Multi-Dex** in Xamarin.Android Build. The build fails with below error.

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2610,3): Error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2610,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. 
Done Building Project "<< MY Project Path>>" (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.


"<< MY Project Path>>" (PackageForAndroid target) (1) ->
(_CompileToDalvikWithDx target) -> 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2610,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2. [<< MY Project Path>>]

    23 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:03:29.78
##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

**Note**
In my local machine everything working fine without any issue.